# When testing for linearity to the logit, do I include all variables in the same step?

Tags: regression, logistic, assumptions

I'm testing for linearity to the logit of the continuous predictor variables in a logistic regression by entering X and X*ln(X) terms into the regression. I have multiple continuous predictors. When I enter them all in the same step, some of the X*ln(X) interactions terms are significant. However, when I use separate models for each predictor variable (rather than adding them all simultaneously), the X*ln(X) interaction term is no longer significant. Why does this happen? And which method is the correct one to use?

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. What do you mean by "step" exactly? Are you including both a given predictor (say weight) & the predictor multiplied by its log (ie, weight*ln(weight) )? If so, why? Note that that isn't an interaction. Can you say more about your situation, your data, your variables, your model, & your goals here? Can you paste in some of the output?

Comment: Don't think of 'steps'.  Think of fully pre-specifying the full model, then making tests and contrasts that pool related terms.  See for example [RMS book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is how to decide whether we need log transformations in the regression:  Including all the variables in the same step does not help. However, the specification you have is not quite rite. ( X and XlogX will give you complicated partial derivatives)
Simple way to do this is:

1. Run the logistic regression with original variables

   ```
       Y=β0+β1X1+β2X2+...
   ```
2. Run the logistic regression with log transformations

   ```
        Y=β0 +β1lnX1+β2 lnX2+...
   ```

   And choose the one with better performance.

Comment: This does not really answer the question

Comment: The OP is referring to a specific procedure for testing linearity (goodness of fit).  They are *not* attempting to introduce log transformations into the model.